# Is there a right way to use one VPS backup file to build a clone VPS with it?

Tags: debian, backup, restore, vps

I tried many times to restore a tar ball from a different server to a fresh installed VPS with the same Linux Debian version (exactly the same) but every time when I restore the tar ball on a different fresh VPS, that VPS would reboot with no problem (at least if the tar ball from a VPS that uses the same virtualization system as the new one), but once it boots back on, I can't use the ssh terminal and even the site won't show up when I call the IP address. 
I simply use the following commands for backup and restore (taken from Ubuntu official help page):

```
sudo tar -cvpzf backup.tar.gz --one-file-system --exclude=/home/user/Backup_Files/backup.tar.gz /
tar -xvpzf backup.tar.gz -C /
```

The reason I want to clone vps is that in case something happens to my vps, I'll be able to rebuild the server from scratch quickly without going through 4 hours of installing and configuration and forgetting something or losing configurations that I've built for years

**So, can you anyone tell me the right way to fully backup a running vps on openvz?**

+mind that no rescue mode in my openvz panel_

Comment: I edited your question. For the future you should keep the question short. So you don't need to write thank you and that this is your first question. Also you should ask one question at a time and the question about build scripts has nothing to do with this one so please create a new question for it. Take a look at the tour of U&L and welcome to U&L.

Comment: DigitalOcean recreates server keys (behind your back) when (re-)create a Droplet. This is for security.

Comment: Thanks..Right now I'm building a script instead of going with backuping a whole server.. I've wasted a lot of time on this silly idea.. At least building a script makes much more sense and much more efficient.. so I advice you all to do that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumping a tarball of / is likely not going to work very well, as you end up overwriting a ton of stuff specific to the "new" machine.  You're much better off just backing up only the things not included in a stock operating system install.  It's generally a better idea to separate your configuration from your data, and separate them both from the operating system and installed packages.

I have a couple of suggestions on how to get the backup you want.

**The easy way**:

Most VPS providers have the option to save a snapshot or image of a server.  Usually it's used to simplify the task of deploying preconfigured servers, but it'll likely do the job nicely for you here.  Taking a snapshot/image from the VPS provider's control panel is usually a one-click operation that gives you an image you can then use to clone a new copy of the server configured identically to the original.

**The harder way**:

1. Use something like etckeeper to back up your configurations.
2. Save off a list of installed packages using something like what's described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages.
3. Tarball up the data directories (usually mostly in /var and /opt).

To restore:

1. Spin up a new machine.
2. Reinstall the package list (which can be easily scripted).
3. Restore the /etc configs from etckeeper.
4. Extract the data tarball to /var or /opt or wherever.

**The way overbuilt and really complicated way**:

Use a configuration management tool like Chef or Puppet to manage your system configs and a real backup tool like Bacula or Dirvish to store your data.  Yeah, overkill for backing up a single server, but technically the "right" way to do things from a sysadmin point of view.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Greg for this excellent explanation.. But honestly they are overwhelming, so let me read them well and try to understand them and be back with feedback.. but really thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Right now I'm building a script instead of going with backuping a whole server.. I've wasted a lot of time on this silly idea.. At least building a script makes much more sense and much more efficient.. so I advice you all to do that..